# Error assigning variable values in a TensorFlow model

Tags: python, tensorflow, debugging, variable-assignment, tensorflow1.15

I have a TensorFlow model that I have loaded from a repository as

```
model = tf.saved_model.load(folder)
```

My objective is to replicate this same model in Jax, and for so I need to understand whether the variable values (weights and biases) loaded are the correct ones.

One way I can recover the value of variable `i` is just

```
vars = model.variables
print(vars[i].numpy())
```

If I `assign` these values into the Jax network, however, I do not recover the right results, so in order to debug, I am trying to analyze the output of specific layers. To do so I need to make sure that weights and biases are the same, eg by assigning them previously. Specifically, if I do

```
numpy_vars = [v.numpy() for v in vars] # This is done in eager mode.

with tf.compat.v1.Session(graph = graph) as sess:
    tvars = tf.compat.v1.trainable_variables()
    tf.compat.v1.variables_initializer(vars).run() #Necessary init. of either tvars/vars
    for v, tv in zip(numpy_vars, tvars):
        tv.assign(v)
    print(tvars[0].eval()) # This returns the value of the variable in graph mode.
    print('------------------------------')
    print(numpy_vars[0])
```

It seems to not be returning the same value, which I expected, although both have the same shape. I am wondering whether this might be because there are initialization operations in the `model.graph`, but am not quite sure. If I instead change the line

```
tv.assign(v)
```

with

```
sess.run(tv.assign(v))
```

I get error

```
TypeError: Argument `fetch` = <tf.Variable 'UnreadVariable' shape=(11, 256) dtype=float32> has invalid type "_UnreadVariable" must be a string or Tensor. (Can not convert a _UnreadVariable into a Tensor or Operation.)
```

Any suggestions of how to assign the values of those variables so that they remain fixed during graph execution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer seems to be this:

```
numpy_vars = [v.numpy() for v in vars]

with tf.compat.v1.Session(graph = graph) as sess:
    tvars = tf.compat.v1.trainable_variables()
    tf.compat.v1.variables_initializer(vars).run()
    print(tvars[0].eval())
    print('------------------------------')
    for v, tv in zip(numpy_vars, tvars):
        tf.compat.v1.assign(tv, v).read_value().eval()
    print(tvars[0].eval())
    print('------------------------------')
    print(numpy_vars[0])
```

After the line

```
tf.compat.v1.assign(tv, v).read_value().eval()
```

I have checked that the weights and biases work appropriately.